# What is the difference between "Intent" and "Problem" for Design Patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I pulled this information from *Design Patterns Explained: A New Perspective on Object-Oriented Design*
According to this book, There are a few key features to a design pattern:
**Name**: It's name
**Intent**: The purpose of the pattern
**Problem**: The problem that the pattern is trying to solve
**Solution**: How the pattern provides a solution to the problem in the context it shows up.
...
There are a few others, but I'm mainly concerned with the difference between Intent and Problem here. I don't really get how the "Intent"(the purpose) of every design pattern isn't to just solve the "Problem".

Answer (score 1):

**Intent** of the pattern briefly describes both the problem and the solution.

**Problem** and **Solution** are more detailed explanations.

You can see it better in examples of design patterns:

- [Factory Method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method)
- [Abstract Factory](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory)
- [Builder](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder)

You can find more design patterns in [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru) or [sourcemaking.com](https://sourcemaking.com).